# How to create a array of PriorityQueues

Tags: java, arrays, priority-queue

I'm writing an algorithm which needs an array of PriorityQueues. Can I get something like:

```
public double[][] distance_table = new double[300][300];
```

Using priorityQueue? I tried:

```
public PriorityQueue<Double>[] queue_table = new PriorityQueue<>(300, comparator)[300];
```

But Netbeans says:

> array required, but PriorityQueue found.

It has an error icon so it isn't a warning.

Comment: Arrays and generics don't mix well. You can use `List<List<PriorityQueue<Double>>>`, for instance with `ArrayLists`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a PriorityQueue of PriorityQueues?

Comment: Yes, I want an array because I want to create a Queue for each vertex. I have 300 vertexes and for each one i want to create a queue with the distances to the rest vertexes. Making a priorityQueue of PriorityQueues is just complicating the code i think For each vertex (the index of the array) I will have an const access to the queue equal 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create arrays of class type as you have shown :
In your case you can do the following :

```
PriorityQueue<Double> queue_table[] = new PriorityQueue[10];
for(int i=0;i<queue_table.length;i++){
   queue_table[i] = new PriorityQueue<>(300, comparator);            
}
```

Here we are first declaring an array of type **PriorityQueue**, not still initializing it. Then we have used loop for initializing it's elements.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting. For curiosity, why i cannot declare the type of the arrays? I mean a one-liner.

Comment: That's how we work with arrays of objects in Java. For more information on that you can visit : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Comment: Okey, I just forgot how to code in Java :) But it seems logic. Thank you very much!